# Chrome for Android: Vibrate API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

When trying to use the Vibrate API in Chrome for Android (tested stable version 43 and dev version 45), it never vibrates. Using the simplest code:

```
window.navigator.vibrate(200);
```

When ran from the Javascript console, it returns true. Vendor prefixes don't fix it. The Chrome Status website shows the API was implemented in version 32.  This code works in Firefox for Android. Is this a problem with Chrome or a problem with my code?

Comment: Strange,I tested this now and it works fine on stable, beta and dev chrome for android, it's not the problem with code or chrome(on my device).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Stupid me, Chrome For Android follows what sound profile you are currently on. While Firefox does not.  So to feel vibrations your sound profile must be on vibrate or above.

Comment: It appears that Chrome on Android refuses to vibrate when the device is in sleep mode. Is there any way to fix that? (I can't find any setting, and there does not seem to be any JavaScript method for that)...?

Comment: I'm stupider, I knew that and I turned up the volume. after I realized that even with loud volume, I was in the only alarms profile.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome vibration api won't work if your Android phone were using specific settings, including but not limited to:

- Silent Mode: on
- Do Not Disturb: on
- Power Saving Mode: on
- Vibration & Touch Feedback: disabled